# Centered axis using ShinobiCharts (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, plot, shinobi

I followed the Quick Start tutorial about Shinobicharts, and I'm wondering how to get a centered graph like this one 
[cos graph](http://www.noelshack.com/2016-25-1466968639-img-8081.png)

I succeded to center the x axis using this :

```
chart.xAxis.axisPositionValue = @0;
```

How can I center the y axis as well? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER:** I am a developer at Shinobi Controls.

The "axisPositionValue" is in data terms on the other axis.

For example, if you had a X-axis with the data range 0 - 10 and a Y-axis with the data range 0 - 100. To get both axes to be in the centre of the chart set the X-axis' "axisPositionValue" & the Y-axis' "axisPositionValue" to 5 like so:

```
chart.xAxis.axisPositionValue = @50;
chart.yAxis.axisPositionValue = @5;
```

Let me know if you have any questions.